# How to cut from a string by reg ex [str] someth [/str] blocks?

Tags: php, regex

Ex: I have a string "my str [str]string string[/str] my str [str]string string[/str] kjnvjsfn"
I`ve tried to do so with RegExp like this

```
preg_match_all('/\[str](.|\n|\r\n)*\[\/str\]/', $str, $arr);
```

but it cuts whole string till last [/str]
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy): Use `*?` instead of `*`

```
preg_match_all('/\[str](.|\n|\r\n)*?\[\/str\]/', $str, $arr);
```

---

**However**, regexes are probably not the best way to go. I.e., it may be *sufficient* for your purpose (if you're e.g. writing them yourself). But if "tags" can be nested then you'll find that the regex approach is becoming very cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your regex non-greedy:

```
preg_match_all('/\[str](.*?)\[\/str\]/s', $str, $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is because the * is greedy. Try use the non greedy *?

```
preg_match_all('/\[str](.|\n|\r\n)*?\[\/str\]/', $str, $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the m and s modifiers to simplify you expression

```
preg_match_all('/\[str\](.*?)\[\/str\]/ms', $str, $arr);
```

This expression is non-greedy and will match anything between [str] and [/str] even if it goes over multiple lines so you don't need to match `\r` or `\n`